# How can I get the users who don't add me back via G+ API?

Tags: api, google-api, google-plus, google-api-php-client

Now, I can view people I have added through Google plus api but I can't find the way to view people that have added me.﻿

https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people#resource

Answer (score 0):

That feature isn't currently available in the API. I'd suggest adding a feature request here: https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list